# looping in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for help with how to run a loop in Google script for part of a function I am writing for a Google sheet (attached to a Google form).

The purpose of this loop is to do what I suppose could be called an inverse v-lookup (i.e. the 'index' column is on the far left of the defined range instead of the far right).

Here is my code:

```
//Formula to align email addresses with ticket number
function getTicketNumber(input) {

//Step 1: define spreadsheet and select sheet
  var sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = sp.getSheetByName("LMS-emails");

//Step 2: define sheet range
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();  
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastColumn)
var values = range.getValues();

//Step 3: forumla   
  for (var i=0; i <=lastRow; i++) { 
    if (values[i][3] == input) {
      return "BOOM!";}
    else {return "fizzle..."}
  }
```

}

I've checked each step of the code leading up to the for loop and everything is working properly. If I define the row # of 'values' it will compare to my 'input' and return "BOOM!" when expected.

However, when I run the function with the for loop included the function returns neither "BOOM!" nor "fizzle..."; the cell is simply blank. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong or the specificities of running a for loop in Google script much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0; i <lastRow.length; i++) {
```

`var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()` is an integer and the length of an integer is undefined hence, it never enters the for loop.
Try adding return "zzz" at the end of the function. See if zzz is shown in the sheet and work back from there, using the Logger and execution transcript to see what is happening

Comment: Thanks! You can see my comment to the other answer below... I've corrected my second statement in the for loop to read: " i <=lastRow," but I must still be doing something wrong because the formula still does not read "BOOM!" when expected.

Comment: That is where the Logger helps. Or return the values so you can see why the compare goes wrong. You need to create your own feedback in the function and solve it based on that.

Comment: Hi Jasper - thanks. Using the Logger was exactly what I need. Much appreciated from a self-taught newbie.

Answer (score 0):

`getLastRow()` returns the position of the last row in your sheet that has content. If you have 10 rows with content, this will return **9** and assign it to `lastRow`.

Your issue is in your for loop condition: `i < lastRow.length`. You aren't comparing `i` to the number of rows in your sheet - can you figure out what exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: Ah! Thank you - silly mistake. I've updated the for loop to now read:

Comment: excuse me - hit the wrong button - anyhow, my for lop now reads: 

    for (var i=0; i <=lastRow; i++) { 
        if (values[i][3] == input) {
          return "BOOM!";}
        else {return "fizzle..."}
      }
    }

however, I now get "fizzle..." for all inputs, even those that should pass "Boom!"

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might look at this question to answer their own questions - the solve was as follows:

OLD CODE

```
//Step 3: forumla   
  for (var i=0; i <=lastRow; i++) { 
    if (values[i][3] == input) {
      return "BOOM!";}
    else {return "fizzle..."}
  }
```

NEW CODE

```
 //Step 3: forumla   
  for (var i=2; i <=lastRow; i++) { 
    if (values[i][3] == input) {
      return "BOOM!";}
    else {return "fizzle..."}
  }
```

Row 3 (i=2 in the new code) is where the data I wanted to iterate through actually began in the spreadsheet, but I don't know the *why* as to that being the solution. Thoughts/explanations welcome!